# update div with values of radio buttons on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I need to collect the values of the checked radio buttons on page load (they are checked on page load) and add them and not only when the user clicks a radio button.

Here's the javascript:

```
$(function ()
{
    updateDivResult();
    $('input:radio').live('click',updateDivResult);
    $('#1').click();
})
function updateDivResult(){
    if ($("input:radio:checked"))
    {
        price = parseFloat($(this).val());
        $('#price').html(roundNumber(price,2));
    }
};
```

roundNumber() is a function defined by me.
Now it only updates the #price div when the user clicks a radio button.

Also, there are a few groups of radio buttons - how do I only add the value of one radio button from the group to the total price?

Thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to loop through the checked values rather than just getting the `val()` of that selector because it seems like there could be more than one checked.

```
function updateDivResult(){
    var price = 0;
    $(":radio:checked").each(function(){
        price += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#price').html(roundNumber(price,2));                
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details?
I can see you are using jQuery.

You could use

$(document).ready(function() {...});

to run some methods when the document is read.

Moreover you could put a specific class to your html elements and use the "each" function to traverse them.

e.g.

$('.your_el').each(function() {...});

In that case the handler will be executed on each object with the class "your_el".

Hope this help, even if the problem is not so clear to me.

Che